# Convert dataframe column names from camel case to snake case

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, camelcasing, snakecasing

I want to change the column labels of a Pandas DataFrame from

```
['evaluationId' , 'createdAt', 'scheduleEndDate', 'sharedTo', ...]
```

to

```
['EVALUATION_ID', 'CREATED_AT', 'SCHEDULE_END_DATE', 'SHARED_TO',...]
```

I have a lot of columns with this pattern "aaaBb" and I want to create this pattern "AAA_BB" of renamed columns

I tried something like :

```
new_columns = [unidecode(x).upper() for x in df.columns]
```

But I don't have idea how to create a solution.

Comment: Have you ever had the opportunity to test the answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to detect the lowercase-UPPERCASE shifts and insert a `_`, then [`str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
df.columns = (df.columns
                .str.replace('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', '_', regex=True)
                .str.upper()
             )
```

Before:

```
  evaluationId createdAt scheduleEndDate sharedTo
0          NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN
```

After:

```
  EVALUATION_ID CREATED_AT SCHEDULE_END_DATE SHARED_TO
0           NaN        NaN               NaN       NaN
```